# EC2 autoscale: bigger instance, not more instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

Reading http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ it looks like Amazon lets you create more virtual machines (EC2 units) automatically when the load on your existing machine gets high.

However, that's not what I want. I want a single virtual machine that becomes more powerful (more RAM, CPU, etc) when the machine load/memory usage is high. How do I do this?

vps.net appears to offer this:

http://vps.net/product/cloud-servers/

under "scale with demand", but I'd like to find an Amazon equivalent.

Comment: Amazon doesn't provide this ability.  EC2's scalability design is around parallel instances, not about reconfiguring existing in-flight instances.

Comment: Where can I find a comparison of VPS that do provide this ability? I know about vps.net and togglebox.com, but there must be more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can scale an EC2 instance up and down, but

- Any automated trigger for this would need to be written by you, calling the EC2 API calls to perform the scaling
- Moving the EC2 instance to a larger or smaller instance type requires shutting down and rebooting the server.

The basic method is:

- stop (not terminate) the instance
- modify-instance-attributes to change the type
- start the instance
- reassociate the Elastic IP address (if any).

I've written an article that provides more information, sample commands, and things to watch out for when performing this resize:

> http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type